# Prepared statement in spark-jdbc

Tags: sql-server, apache-spark, spark-jdbc

I am trying to read the data from the MSSQL database using Spark jdbc with a specified offset. So the data should be loaded only after the specified timestamp which would be this offset. I tried to implement it by providing a query in jdbc configuraions, however, I did not found a possibility to create a prepared statement with parameterized values. In this case, I want to parameterize an offset which would change after each application launch. How can I implement it using jdbc options?

All the database configs reside in the application.conf file. 
This is the way I read from the database:

```
def jdbcOptions(query: String) = Map[String,String](
    "driver" -> config.getString("sqlserver.db.driver"),
    "url" -> config.getString("sqlserver.db.url"),
    "dbtable" -> s"(select * from TestAllData where update_database_time >= '2019-03-19 12:30:00.003') as subq,
    "user" -> config.getString("sqlserver.db.user"),
    "password" -> config.getString("sqlserver.db.password"),
    "customSchema" -> config.getString("sqlserver.db.custom_schema")
  )

    val testDataDF = sparkSession
      .read
      .format("jdbc")
      .options(jdbcOptions())
      .load()
```

Instead a query should look almost like this:

```
s"(select * from TestAllData where update_database_time >= $tmstp) as subq
```

Comment: You can just put your $tmstp directly in query if I understand your question correctly.

Comment: Because it is not the best and secure way to embed parameters into queries using String and not prepared statements.

Comment: Are you going to run this job depends on parameters from users?

Comment: I am going to provide a changing parameter which I read from Kafka, so I do not want to hardcode the value

Comment: Do you want to protect your system from sql injection?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I need it for

Comment: As far as I know, there is no way to do it using spark built in possibilities. However, you could try third party library that could validate your query before inserting in spark reader.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no prepared statement in Spark-jdbc, so there are not other ways except for setting parameters in a String:

```
val dayColumn = "update_database_time"
val dayValue = "2019-03-19 12:30:00.003"

s"(select * from TestAllData where $dayColumn > '$dayValue') as subq"
```